# Change background of selected item bootstrap 2.3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using `bootstrap 2.3` stacked tabs http://jsfiddle.net/28Hv5/

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
   <li><%= link_to 'first', '#' %></li>
   <li><%= link_to 'second', '#' %></li>
   <li><%= link_to "third", '#' %></li>    
</ul>
```

How would I make the below markup for selected item?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of the pseudo classes of css it's easy.

```
ul.nav li.active a, ul.nav li.active a:hover {
    background: blue;
    position: relative;
    border-top-left-radius: 0 !important; /* remove the default bootstrap's border-radius*/
    color: #fff;
}

ul.nav li.active a:before {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 18px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 18px solid transparent;
    border-right:10px solid blue;
    position: absolute;
    left: -10px;
    content:"";
    top: 0;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/28Hv5/1/)